# Finding all eigenvalues and eigenvectors by proofing

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be given by T(w,z) = (z,w)

We can have $T(w,z) = \lambda(w,z)$

Two conditions: $$z = \lambda w$$ $$w = \lambda z$$
We sub $z$ into $w$ we get $$w = \lambda^2w$$

Then we solve for $\lambda$ we get $$\lambda = \pm 1$$

Eigenvector to eigenvalue:

$\lambda$ = 1 are $$(w,w) = span(1,1)$$
$\lambda = -1 $ are $$(w,-w) = span(1,-1)$$

What is the reason that the following equation end up with $(w,w)$ and $(w,-w)$?

Comment: Is the map $T(w,z)=(w,z)$ or $T(w,z)=(z,w)$?

Comment: You mean $T(w,z) = (z,w)$?

Comment: @amsmath yes $T(w,z) = (z,w)$. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

Here I assume that $V$ is $\mathbb K^2$.

These are indeed the two eigenvalues of $T$. Since $T$ is the "swapping coordinates map", we can also see that these are the eigenvectors for the following reasons:

$(1)$ It is clear that, if the two coordinates are equal, then swapping the coordinates does not change the vector. That is, $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue since swapping the coordinates of a vector of the form $(w,w)$ does not change the vector.

$(2)$ If a vector has coordinates that only differ by a sign, then swapping the coordinates still yields a vector whose coordinates only differ by a sign. That is, $\lambda=-1$ is an eigenvalue since swapping the coordinates of a vector of the form $(w,-w)$ yields a vector of the form $(-w,w)=-(w,-w)$.

---

More algebraically, to find the eigenvectors we just solve for the solution systems to $$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & -1 \\ -1 & \lambda\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w\\z\end{bmatrix}=0$$ for $\lambda=\pm 1$. This is because the matrix on the left is $\lambda I-A$ where $A$ is the matrix of $T$.